# Getting infinite loop when making an axios get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

When I make a get request with Axios to an api I am getting an infinite loop in the useEffect hook and I thought for sure that adding the second option of "[]" would tell it to only run once. Is there something I am missing or overlooked? The console.log is showing me that it is making an infinite loop.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { getCookie } from '../utils/util';




const Details = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    let country;    
    const queryURL = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/`;

    useEffect(() => {
        country = getCookie('title');
        console.log(country);
        axios.get(queryURL + country).then((res) => {
            setData(res.data);
        }, []);

    })

    return (
        <>
            details
        </>
    )
}

export default Details;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **You need to put empty array (dependency) after the `callback` function:**

**Change to:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  country = getCookie("title");
  console.log(country);
  axios.get(queryURL + country).then((res) => {
    setData(res.data);
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: You should mark the answer as correct if it helped.

Comment: Appreciate that! @MrMythical