# React APP makes a ton of API Calls and crashes

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, tradingview-api

I am making a simple app that makes an api request to my local server and gets some data and puts it on a chart from trading view. This should be pretty simple as everything is just for practice, but when I change some of the values on my server and make the call, the app keeps making the call like 35 times before the server crashes and then the app just says

> "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

and doesn't display the data as it should.

This is the whole code, it has two parts. One parts makes the call to get example data of name and another call to get example data that will go to the chart (the second part is the issue.)

This is the code just for the second part:

```
getBars: async (
  symbolInfo,
  resolution,
  periodParams,
  onHistoryCallback,
  onErrorCallback
) => {
  try {
    if (resolution === '1D') {
      resolution = 1440;
    }
    const response2 = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/chart');

    console.log('got bars data');
    const bars = response2.data.map((el) => ({
      time: new Date(el.timeInterval.minute).getTime(), // date string in api response
      low: el.low,
      high: el.high,
      open: Number(el.open),
      close: Number(el.close),
      volume: el.volume,
    }));

    if (bars.length) {
      onHistoryCallback(bars, { noData: false });
    } else {
      onHistoryCallback(bars, { noData: true });
    }
    console.log('bars done');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({ err });
  }
};
```

So what happens is that the console.log "got bars data" and "bars done" repeats many times until my localhost:8000 server crashes and then the app gives the error I showed above, because of this it doesn't display the data. I have no Idea why this may be happening,

This is what the data looks like for the one that does not works:

```
{"timeInterval":{"minute":"2022-03-14T23:45:00Z"},"volume":0.05,"high":3.910209183178435e-9,"low":3.910209183178435e-9,"open":"3.910209183178435e-09","close":"3.910209183178435e-09"}
```

This is for the one that works:

```
{"timeInterval":{"minute":"2022-03-17T15:00:00Z"},"volume":0.05,"high":0.00001255389794727055,"low":0.00001255389794727055,"open":"1.255389794727055e-05","close":"1.255389794727055e-05"}
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

**EDIT**

I just noticed, with the data set that works,  `console.log('got bars data')` and `console.log('bars done')` don't occur for some reason, but the data still shows up on the chart even though the console doesn't log.

Comment: How are you initiated the call?

Comment: @RyanZeelie sorry a bout the late response, from what is supposed to be the backend on my local server, the call is being made through an axios.post request

Comment: Not sure its entirely related but does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69023272/getting-infinite-loop-when-making-an-axios-get-request) help?

Comment: You should post when and how you're calling `getBars`